# Physicist path integral and cylinder set measures

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, definition, path-integral

### Path integral via discretization

So let me start with what seems to be the point of view of physicists (corrections are highly appreciated since this is just what I understood!). Let a quantum system with coordinates $q_a$ and momenta $p_b$ be given satisfying commutation relations $$[q_a,p_b]=i\delta_{ab}.$$

Further suppose the system has a Hamiltonian $H$ which is time-independent. Usually in that setting the path integral is introduced as a means to compute the transition amplitude

$$\langle q',t'|q,t\rangle=\langle q'|e^{-iH(t'-t)}|q\rangle\equiv\int\mathfrak{D}x(t)  \exp\left\{iS[x(t)]\right\}$$

This is usually defined by a discretization procedure allied to a Wick rotation to Euclidean time $\tau = it$ to deal with convergence. The right discretization seems to be derived by slicing the time interval, evaluating $\langle q',t'|q,t\rangle$ to first order in $t'-t$, and imposing some ordering convention. So, for example with a Lagrangian $L = T - V$ the above integral would be *defined* as something of the form

$$\int\mathfrak{D}x(t) \exp\left\{iS[x(t)]\right\}\equiv\lim_{N\to \infty} C_N\int \prod_{k=1}^N dx_k \exp \left\{i\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{m}{2}\frac{(x_k-x_{k-1})^2}{\epsilon_N^2}-V(x_k)\right\}\tag{1}$$

So: a path integral in Physics is *defined* by the continuum limit of these aforementioned discretizations.

### Cylinder set measures and Gaussian Measures

Now there's the mathematicians point of view on which one studies integration over locally convex vector spaces which are infinite dimensional. In that case, if $E$ is such a space we perform two definitions:

> **Definition**: Let $E$ be a locally convex vector space. A **cylinder set** is defined to be a subset $C\subset E$ of the form $$C=\{x\in E : (\ell_1(x),\dots,\ell_n(x))\in C_0\}$$
>   where $C_0\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a Borel subset and $\ell_k\in E^\ast$ are continuous linear functionals. Equivalently, it is a preimage $C = P^{-1}(C_0)$ of a Borel set under a continuous linear map $P : E\to \mathbb{R}^n$.
>
> **Definition:** Let $E$ be a locally convex vector space. A cylinder set measure (CSM) $\nu$ is a nonnegative additive set function defined on the $\sigma$-algebra generated by cylinder sets of $E$ such that for any continuous linear $P : E\to \mathbb{R}^n$ the set function $$\nu\circ P^{-1} : B\mapsto \nu(P^{-1}(B))$$ is countably additive.

Given the definition of a CSM, there may be true measures associated to it in other spaces. This is connected to the idea of a radonifying map [described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radonifying_function). Moreover *the Wiener measure arises in this form out of the canonical Gaussian CSM in a Hilbert space*, see [this post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Wiener_space).

### Comparison

If we now compare there are a few points to mention:

1. It seems that cylinder sets capture discretizations. If $x$ is a continuous path, $(\ell_1(x),\dots, \ell_n(x))$ is an $n$-point discretization. To be even more precise in the case of paths we could take $\ell_k(x) = x(t_k)$ for some $t_1,\dots, t_n$ in the interval. In the same way we could take $\ell_k(x) = a_k$ some Fourier coefficient of $x(t)$. I've seem both things done in Physics.
2. It seems cylinder set measures are in fact a way to define "a measure per discretization". So for each discretization we give a measure - integrate over $n$ points, integrate over $n$ Fourier coefficients, so forth.

   Comparing to (1), for example, it seems a CSM would comprise the various measures for finite $N$ inside the limit brought together.
3. The radonification process on cylinder set measures seems to be the counterpart of the limit. I just don't see how to make this precise.

Still, the connection doesn't feel complete for me. The issue is that to define a cylinder set measure we must define $\nu$ on **the whole algebra generated by cylinder sets**.

The Physicist approach seems to do this exactly for a specific collection of cylinder sets. Either for the ones with $\ell_k(x) = x(t_k)$ or for the ones with $\ell(x_k)=a_k$ a Fourier coefficient.

But there are infinitely many other choices of the $\ell_k$ which give rise to many more cylinder sets. And one would need still to define $\nu$ on the $\sigma$-algebra itself.

Moreover, the Physicist takes a limit and the Mathematician uses a radonifying map, I don't see how the two things are connected, although they seem to be.

**The question**: is there really a relation between cylinder set measures and the Physicist discretization of a path integral? If so, how the relation can be made more precise? If not, why not, considering the similarities?

For this discussion, please let us consider the Euclidean path integral. So the issue here *is not the imaginary exponent*.

Comment: The Wiener measure in the space of paths, used to rigorously define the euclidean path integrals (the so-called Feynman-Kac formula) originates from a cylindrical measure. Further details on the connection between path integrals and cylindrical measures (or promeasures, using french terminology) can be found in [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4899-0319-8) and [this one](https://www.amazon.it/Mathematical-Theory-Feynman-Path-Integrals/dp/3540769544)

Comment: The main obstruction to simply using cylindrical measures to define path integrals is that since in general they are only finitely additive, it is not possible to integrate general functions with respect to them, but only cylindrical ones. Thus one looks for a probability measure that suitably extends, usually in a "bigger space", the cylindrical measure. With respect of such bigger measure it is then possible to integrate non-cylindrical functions such as the exponential of the action (or of the interaction part, since the free part is used to define the measure itself).

Comment: Thanks for the references @yuggib! I've obtained DeWitt's book and it seems very helpful, I'll certainly read it in detail. In fact I was aware that the Wiener (Gaussian) measure can be obtained out of cylindrical measures (CM) and this "bigger space" extension. In that case one starts with the canonical Gaussian CM on a Hilbert space, if I understood. What I'm wondering is if discretizations like (1) in the post, give rise to CMs, even ones which cannot later be turned into real measures, and if so, how we bridge the approaches. Is it really the case as I suspect?

Comment: One would need to prove that such discretizations give rise to cylindrical measures, although it seems possible. One could maybe see the procedure of fixing one time as a continuous linear functional on the space of (everywhere defined) paths (the "delta" distribution, associating to a path its value at a given time), and build the cylinders using only these distributions. However, I do not know if this is an idea that has been explored.

Comment: Let me also comment that every cylindrical measure can be seen as a true measure  on a bigger space, although such big space in some cases can become extremely "big" and nasty to characterize. For the Gaussian measure, the bigger space is a Banach space, but in general it is the product, over all weakly closed subspaces of finite codimension, of the Cech compactifications of the quotients of the original LCV space w.r.t. the aforementioned subspaces.

Comment: I believe what you mention of the "delta" distribution associating to a path its value at a given time is what I mentioned in point (1) of the comparison. My issue, as I alluded to, is that this gives *a subset of the cylinder sets*. In other words, not all cylinder sets arise from this choice of projectors. So I don't see why defining the CM for this subset - which seems the physicist approach - is enough. Thanks for pointing out that last result. I was unaware that it was always possible to realize a CM as a true measure.

Comment: CM can be defined in more generality than for LCV spaces. It is enough to have a set $E$, and a vector space of functions $E'\subset \mathbb{R}^E$ from such set $E$ to the reals. Then one constructs the $\sigma$-algebra of cylinders on the set in the way you defined, but only restricting to the action of $\ell_k\in E'$. That means that defining the measures associated to each time in $[0,T]$ can be enough to define a cylindrical measure (just taking the linear span of the delta distributions as $E'$).

Comment: Such more general construction is explained in [this book](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bfm%3A978-94-009-3873-1%2F1.pdf) -- sorry I could not find a better link.

Comment: My advice to beginners in the area of rigorous functional integration with the aim of understanding path integrals in QFT is never ever use cylindrical measures. In infinite dimension only use probability measures and the latter always on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of a reasonable topological space.