# Interpreting generating functional as sum of all diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, path-integral, partition-function, graph-theory

The generating functional is defined as:
$$Z[J] = \int \mathcal{D}[\phi] \exp\Big[\frac{i}{\hbar}\int d^4x [\mathcal{L} + J(x)\phi(x)]\Big].$$

I know this object is used as a tool to generate correlation functions by taking functional derivatives, but does it have any interpretation on its own? In [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/107058/288281) the answer states that it can be interpreted as the sum of all possible Feynman diagrams. Is this interpretation from Taylor expanding the exponential in $Z[J]$?

Comment: Since it generates all the correlation functions, it is a sum of all possible correlation functions with different numbers of fields for the different terms in the summation. Each correlation function consists of multiple Feynman diagrams.

Comment: @flippiefanus Wouldn't we need to first act on $Z$ with functional derivatives to do that? How does $Z$ contain any diagrams before differentiating?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The generating functional *by definition* is an object that encodes the Green's functions in a series as $$Z[J]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n!}\int dx_1\cdots dx_n J(x_1)\cdots J(x_n) \langle \phi(x_1)\cdots \phi(x_n)\rangle\tag{1}.$$

This is the case because it is defined so that the correlators can be extracted as $$\langle \phi(x_1)\cdots\phi(x_n)\rangle = \dfrac{\delta^n Z[J]}{\delta J(x_1)\cdots \delta J(x_n)}\bigg|_{J=0}\tag{2}.$$

The fact that $Z[J]$ is given by the expression you wrote can then be seem as a consequence of the Dyson-Schwinger equations, for example. See this [answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/747031/what-does-it-mean-for-a-field-to-be-defined-by-a-measure/747034#747034) to a question you asked previously for more into this.

So, answering your current question, since each correlator is a sum of Feynman diagrams it is indeed possible to see $Z[J]$ as a sum over all possible Feynman diagrams in view of its definition, equation (1).

Comment: Wow your answer seems to reveal something a lot deeper than I had originally had in mind. So the functional measure $d\mu$ that is of interested in constructive quantum field theory is the link between your (1) an the $Z[J]$ I wrote?

Comment: Generating functionals and measures are related by a kind of Fourier transform (that is the Bochner-Minlos theorem). So yes, there should be a measure underlying $Z$ and people in constructive field theory try to find ways to define it. Informally this measure is $d\mu(\phi) = {\scr D}\phi e^{i S}$, but this is of course not rigorous and not a definition of anything. In fact, defining this measure is extremely hard.

Comment: Thank you, this is now clear. Also if you have any suggestions for learning more about constructive field theory that would be great.

Comment: Even for free theories one cannot make sense of $d\mu(\phi)=D\phi\ e^{iS}$ as a measure. However, what constructive QFT manages to do in some models like $\phi_{2+1}^{4}$ is to make sense of $d\mu(\phi)=D\phi\ e^{-S_E}$, where $S_E$ is the Euclidean action, as a measure.

Answer (score 6):

Perturbatively, one can formally argue that the [partition function/path integral/functional integral/generating functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_integration) can be written as
$$\begin{align} Z[J]~=~&\int {\cal D}\frac{\phi}{\sqrt{\hbar}}~\exp\left\{ \frac{i}{\hbar}\left(S[\phi] +J_k \phi^k \right)\right\}  \cr
~\sim~& \underbrace{\exp\left\{\frac{i}{\hbar} S_{\neq 2}\left[ \frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{\delta}{\delta J}\right] \right\}}_{\text{bag of vertices}} 
 \underbrace{\exp\left\{- \frac{i}{2\hbar} J_k (S_2^{-1})^{k\ell} J_{\ell} \right\}}_{\text{bag of propagators}} , \end{align}$$
cf. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/270456/2451). All possible diagrams are generated by performing the functional $J$-differentiations.